Compile and test classes generated by Maven template engine project
My Maven project is a template engine that generates some java classes from user input data (provided as a json file). It is simply composed of a top level module (myproject-parent, type pom) and a core module (myproject-core) containing the engine.
The engine is realised thanks to the "Apache FreeMarker" maven dependency.
The core module contains some unit tests that execute the engine and generate some classes. Now I would like to compile and import them into dedicated tests in order to check the accuracy of the generated code.
Can this be done directly in the core module through a dedicated phase or goal? Or eventually in a separate test module?
Ultimately, is it possible to package these generated classes with the rest of the project (as examples for user)?

I used my custom maven plugin for that.

You could create your own Maven plugin that has a custom goal, maybe called generate-classes. Won't be hard to move your code to a Mojo structure. Take a look over https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html.

Thank's for your feedback :) I'll look into this solution
